# assign a attribute using getattr

Tags: python, getattr

I try to assign value to attributes of some calss
like the following:

```
for name in dir(modelType):
      if request.get(name):
            getattr(model, name) = request.get(name)
```

but get the excption:
"can't assign to function call"

how can I change attributes without knowing them at complie time?

Comment: This is very unsafe. What if someone passes an id= parameter in the URL? They would overwrite existing data. Is this Django or a similar framework? You should use proper form handling to save data.

Answer (score 25):

You use `setattr()` to assign values to attributes.

See:  http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#setattr

Comment: Exactly, I was about to post the same thing but was blocked out for answering too fast!

Comment: :-)  Never boring here on SO.

Answer (score 10):

```
setattr(model, name, request.get(name))
```

but I'd recommend saving request data in a dictionary, dedicated class, or accessing it directly - unless you're doing specific metaprogramming/introspection, setattr is often the wrong tool for the job.